# How to get/load blob image using

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, blob

Im trying to load an image, field of longblob and I have a 1 row(id,design,name) data in my table. but when I click the button to show the image and it not showing it.

I have a GetImage.aspx to call my method

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        Using conn As New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MySQLConnection").ToString())
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT design FROM mytable")
            Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
            conn.Open()
            Context.Response.Clear()
            Context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
            Context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageData)
            Context.Response.End()

        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

And this is my control button to show the image from my default page

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Image1.ImageUrl = "GetImage.aspx?"
End Sub
```

Please help I dont understand why my image is not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines are out of order:

```
Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
conn.Open()
```

You need to open the connection before you execute the command:

```
conn.Open()
Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
```

You also need to associate the connection with the command:

```
cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT design FROM mytable", conn)
```

Comment: I already tried. But it still not showing my image file. Di i have a problem to my button when i am using this? Image1.ImageUrl = "GetImage.aspx?". Thans

Comment: Do you see the image if you go directly to that url in your browser?

Comment: You mean if I run the GetImage? I run it but there is no image showing. But in my mysql database when I view it has a content image JPEG.

Comment: What happens if you remove the try/catch? You're swallowing the exception, and any information it might have about what went wrong.

Comment: yes! there is it gives me Connection must be valid and open. at this part "Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())"